# How do I make a squeezed balloon?

Tags: collision, soft-body

Is there a scientific way to have a balloon squeezed as if between two planes (or in a vise)?  In other words, have the sphere maintain its volume while it is deformed between two parallel planes?
[update]
This video shows how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6z4C63l0tc
Thanks to David Ward for his tutorial.

Comment: I think soft bodies keep their volume by default. Have you tried animating the walls and the sphere? How did it turn out?

Comment: I've tried that, but the sphere only forms dimples and doesn't bulge out the way you'd expect.